# Defining a variable with Interface or with Class

Tags: c#, class, interface

this popped into my head recently:

We have an Interface:

```
interface IPerson { }
```

and a Class that implements said Interface:

```
class Person : IPerson{ }
```

Now, what is the preferred way of initializing a Person-Variable, this:

```
Person person = new Person();
```

or:

```
IPerson person = new Person();
```

Using Type Inference and Intellisense

```
var person = new Person();
```

reveals that person is of type Person, instead of IPerson.
Also I was thinking of something like this:

```
List<IPerson> persons;
```

vs. this:

```
List<Person persons;
```

What is the preferred way of declaring a variable or defining a Collection in this case, also in terms of future refactorings etc.
If this is a duplicate question, please tell.

Best regards

Comment: This is opinion-based. It depends on so many further designs in your program that there isn't a black and whit answer.

Comment: You use an interface when you might change the implementation at run-time or when you are using a general purpose library that could support multiple implementations. Are you doing that?

Comment: @Enigmativity specifically, i am using Windows Image Acquisition Interop, which provides 2 Interfaces for every class, e.g. you have an IDeviceManager-Interface, a DeviceManager-Interface and a DeviceManagerClass, which is confusing to me. DeviceManagerClass implements DeviceManager and DeviceManager implements IDeviceManager. I'd have to further look into the type-definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you prefer to use interfaces. Suppose that you have a list of `Person` and you also have a kind of person, like `SuperHero`:

```
class SuperHero : IPerson{ }
```

In this case, `SuperHero` may inherit from `Person` but as an example we may suppose that has not sense. So you have 2 classes implementing `IPerson`.

If you have a variable of type `Person`, you can't manage `SuperHero`s. And if you have a `List<Person>` you only can store `Person`, not `SuperHero`s.

If you need work with any `IPerson`, you must use interfaces:

```
List<IPerson> list = new List<IPerson>();
list.Add(new Person());
list.Add(new SuperHero());
```

And a point about "var". If you use var, the compiler change var for the type that you use at right. You can force with a casting:

```
var person = (IPerson)new Person();
```

When you work with OLE automation and COM objects, in .NET you need an inplementation of the interfaces. That implementacion has the Class suffix. But you can work with the interfaces, without the Class suffix. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/blogs/mshneer/vs-2010-compiler-error-interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead

Comment: casting when using type inference seems out of place

Comment: @HalilIbrahimÖzcan - It's perfectly fine, but a it odd. Personally, pardon the pun, I'd do this: `var person = new Person() as IPerson;`.

Comment: Without casting, person will be of Person class. Then, you can't do later, for example, person = new SuperHero(). With IPerson casting, you can use person variable to reference any IPerson implementation